# Eclipse error: executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library

Tags: java, android, eclipse

First of all, I started to learn JAVA programming. When I click on Eclipse icon, I see this fault.

Firstly, I saw first fault, **JVM terminated. Exit code=2.** Then, I read several solution method in this site. I changed code in''eclipse.ini''. But, My problem do not solve. I saw different problem.

Now, When I click on Eclipse icon, I see this fault.
**''The eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library.''**
More power to you!

Comment: A short time ago, I removed eclipse. Then, I launch eclipse. At the same time, I use WinRar. But, again I see fault; ''JVM terminated. Exit code=2.''

Comment: I resolved my problem. My subject isn't different other subjects.  Thanks a lot.